# Protect file from system modifications

Tags: linux

I am working on a linux computer which is locked down and used in kiosk mode to run only one application.  This computer cannot be updated or modified by the user.  When the computer crashes or freezes the OS rebuilds or modifies the ld-2.5.so file.  This file needs to be locked down without allowing even the slightest change to it (there is an application resident which requires ld-2.5.so to remain unchanged and that is out of my control). Below are the methods I can think of to protect ld-2.5.so but wanted to run it by the experts to see if I am missing anything.

- I modified the fstab to mount the EXT3 filesystem as EXT2 to disable journaling.  Also set the DUMP and FSCK values to "0" to disable those processes.
- Performed a "chattr +i ld-2.5.so" on the file but there are still system processes that can overwrite this protection.
- I could attempt to trap the name of the processes which are hitting ld-2.5.so and prevent this.

Any ideas or hints would be greatly appreciated.
-Matt (CentOS 5.0.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chattr +i` should be fine in most circumstances.

The ld-*.so files are under /usr/lib/ and /usr/lib64/. If /usr/ is a separate partition, you also might want to mount that partition read only on a kiosk system.

Do you have, by any chance, some automated updating/patching of said PC configured? ld-*.so is part of glibc and basically should only change if the glibc package is updated.

Comment: kkeller - thank you very much for the response and taking the time out of your day to assist.  On the system I am working on /usr is not on a separate partition.  The machine only has two partions (one for /boot and another for everything else).  I am not worried about a user editing ld-2.5.so because the machine is locked down so tightly that a user can only run one application and cannot get to an xterm or menu to do anything else.  This machine is not configured for automated updates.  As a matter of fact it will never be plugged into a network or internet to receive updates.

Comment: Ran out of room to type......this machine has an engineering purpose and never connects to the internet or a network to receive downloads.  It's completely standalone.  I'm hoping that LINUX will not be able to override the chattr +i and change ld-2.5.so for any reason.  I would rather the computer crash and need a cycle rather than have that file changed.  Thank you for the help kkeller!!!!  I appreciate it greatly:)

Comment: @Matt - If you are so worried about the file changing, you might want to read up on `inotify`. This offers a way to have a program watch changes to a file and act to them.